# Making sense of monero-wallet-rpc get_transfers returning 3 TXs for a TXID

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, transaction-data

I'm writing an app where I fetch and transparently display all TXs for a wallet.

When I send a POST request to the `monero-wallet-rpc` with the `get_transfers` method and the `in: true` parameter, I get three outputs for the same TXID.

1. Amount is 0
2. Very small amount
3. Actual TX amount with added `suggested_confirmations_threshold: 1` object property

I assume #2 is the TX fee, and #3 is the actual TX to the receiver. Not exactly sure what #1 is.

How can I make sense of this returned data?

Request (NodeJS):

```
fetch(config.xmr.wallet_RPC_URL + "/json_rpc", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                jsonrpc: "2.0",
                id: "0",
                method: "get_transfers",
                params: {
                    in: true
                }
            })
```

Response:

```
{
  address: 'mywalletaddr',
  amount: 0,
  confirmations: 788609,
  double_spend_seen: false,
  fee: 20000000000,
  height: 1511844,
  locked: false,
  note: '',
  payment_id: '0000000000000000',
  subaddr_index: { major: 0, minor: 0 },
  subaddr_indices: [ { major: 0, minor: 0 } ],
  timestamp: 1518905851,
  txid: 'thetxid',
  type: 'in',
  unlock_time: 0
}
{
  address: 'mywalletaddr',
  amount: 0,
  confirmations: 788609,
  double_spend_seen: false,
  fee: 20000000000,
  height: 1511844,
  locked: false,
  note: '',
  payment_id: '0000000000000000',
  subaddr_index: { major: 0, minor: 0 },
  subaddr_indices: [ { major: 0, minor: 0 } ],
  timestamp: 1518905851,
  txid: 'thetxid',
  type: 'in',
  unlock_time: 0
}
{
  address: 'mywalletaddr',
  amount: 874585636991,
  amounts: [ 874585636991 ],
  confirmations: 788609,
  double_spend_seen: false,
  fee: 20000000000,
  height: 1511844,
  locked: false,
  note: '',
  payment_id: '0000000000000000',
  subaddr_index: { major: 0, minor: 0 },
  subaddr_indices: [ { major: 0, minor: 0 } ],
  suggested_confirmations_threshold: 1,
  timestamp: 1518905851,
  txid: 'thetxid',
  type: 'in',
  unlock_time: 0
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the actual request payload.

Comment: @jtgrassie done

Comment: not the response, the request.

Comment: @jtgrassie My bad, fixed.

Comment: Did you send to yourself?

Comment: @jtgrassie No. Almost all TXIDs that get returned have 3 entries. This is just one example.

Comment: That is indeed odd then.

Comment: @jtgrassie I appended all TXIDs from the RPC response to array and sorted. https://ibb.co/3TpzBWQ. As you can see most of them have 3 entries. I figured this is expected behavior, I'm just not well versed with the blockchain to understand it.

Comment: No it's not expected. I don't have *any* duplicates. You should be able to resolve with a `rescan_bc` from the earliest height you ever received anything.

Comment: @jtgrassie `rescan_blockchain` fixed it! Thank you.

Comment: Glad that sorted it. Coincidentally, I mentioned the CLI `rescan_bc` instead of the RPC `rescan_blockchain` as the former allows you to set the height to rescan from; either way glad you're fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Running the `rescan_blockchain` method fixed the issue. Now only 1 TX is returned per TXID.

Thanks to @jtgrassie for helping resolve this.